# Ya.share2 и динамические материалы

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Поделиться от Яндекса не работает на материалы добавленные динамически (ajax). Кнопки просто не отображаются в новых материалах. Подскажите, может есть какое решение?

Answer (score 0):

Хм, если добавить $.getScript( "http://test_script.js" ) того же скрипта отвечающего за "поделиться", все работает, но правильно ли так делать..